# Automate PDF contents using nightwatch/Cucumber

Tags: node.js, pdf, automation, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch/NodeJs using cucumber for Automation. I have a lot of areas where PDF's are generated and needs to be verified. Is there any way by which I can verify PDF contents which are downloaded including text/Images etc??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are looking to generate PDF through nodeJS then below link will help you:
https://medium.com/@svsh227/generate-pdf-using-node-js-cfb1fac36625

Comment: PDF will be automatically generated by the application itself.
I was asking like after generating whether there is any method of checking the contents inside PDF through automation? @Shubham Verma

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pdfjs-dist` package to read the contents of a PDF. In my experience it has worked **most** of the time. I have had a few instances where it returned no content even though I could visibly see that the file had text in it. I haven't tried to dig in to see why that was but the majority of the time it has worked for me without issue. Also, I have only used it to verify text. I haven't tried to use it for images so I'm not sure if it can do that. You can find more details [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

This will get you as far as getting all the text into an array. What you do with it from there is up to you.

```
pdfjs.getDocument('path/to/your/file.pdf').then(function(document) {
    document.getPage(1).then(function(page) {                    
        page.getTextContent().then(function(text) {
            const allText = text.items.map(function(s) { return s.str }).concat('');
            //console.log(allText);
        });                   
    });
});
```